# cPanel, Laravel TokenMismatchException with Cookies not being set

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, cpanel

I recently moved my laravel application to a production server rather than just developing locally. However since doing so I have been unable to login to the site as I keep running into `Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException`.

I never had the issue on the local server, just when I ported it over the production server.

I have looked into the tokens and they never match at all. My code is as follows:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    // Check ajax requests for token validity via the header.
    // app.js has the code to grab form tokens and put it in
    // a header, well validate it here if its a post AJAX
    if (Request::ajax() && Request::getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        if (Session::getToken() != Request::header('X-CSRF-Token'))
        {
            throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
        }
    } else {
        if (Request::getMethod() == 'POST' && Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
        {
            throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
        }
    }
});
```

The error occurs when I am trying to compare `Session::token()` to `Input::get('_token)`

So my question is, is there something blatantly obvious that I am missing in regards to the difference between tokens on a local server to that of a production server?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

~Additional Information~

From the other sources I've found there are similar issues where the session isn't persisting. I'm already on Laravel 4.1 so the `lifetime` and `expire_on_close` are already set to the default of `120` and `false`. I have also tried changing the session driver to file/database/cookie all with the same outcome.

~Another Update~

Ok, somewhere a bit closer, looking into browser resources, on my local server a cookie is set laravel_session, however on my web server this is not appearing at all. So think this is related it.

Comment: I second this. I'm having this same trouble and I can't determine the cause. The `Session::token()` and `Input::get('_token')` are often unmatched. I'm interested in seeing the fix. I'm still searching myself.

Comment: Are other session variables persisting? I'm thinking it could be a problem with your session cookie path or domain or maybe you have the secure flag set (https only sessions)

Comment: Other values are persisting and the cookie path/domain are the default which work on my local server. As to the secure flag that is set to false.

Comment: Ok, somewhere a bit closer, looking into browser resources, on my local server a cookie is set laravel_session, however on my web server this is not appearing at all. So think this is related it.

Comment: I am also having this issue. On my local server sessions and cookies are set fine, but on my web server on the server side session file is written. On the client side neither cookies nor sessions are set. (Laravel 4.1 - fresh install) (cpanel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't solve this. In the end though I found that is was related to the use of cPanel, as soon as I used another hosting provider without cPanel the issue has never occured.